# Providing working-directory in AWS CLI ECS run-task command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there any way of overriding the working-directory from the task-definition default when starting a task from the CLI? It seems like a fairly easy thing and a potentially important thing, but, if it is available, it looks like it's going to be very obscure, in that it's not advertised in the CLI documentation or UI.

Comment: Is this tied to the container itself? Not ECS?

Comment: I don't understand your question. All of the directories that we could be talking about are running in a container in ECS. The container engine, which is ECS, has a working directory to begin executing from. We configure this, in ECS, in the task definition, and I'm just asking if there's a way to tell it a different one when starting. You can do this with Docker via the `--workdir` parameter: `docker run --workdir <path> <image>`.

Comment: Apologies - I wasn't sure if ECS was using the default WORKDIR specified in the Dockerfile or a custom parameter.